# What are the restapis to get Coverage,technical debt,unit test success density and unit test failure density json data for SonarQube 6.3.1 in Postman?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube6.3

The rest apis for Sonarqube 6.0 version is:-

> 1.(SonarqubeUrl)/api/issues/search=>For Technical Debt.
>   2.(SonarqubeUrl)/api/resources?metrics=ncloc,coverage=>For Code Coverage.
>   3.(SonarqubeUrl)/api/resources?metrics=ncloc,test_success_density=>For Unit Test Success.
>   4.(SonarqubeUrl)//api/resources?metrics=ncloc,test_failure_density=>For
>   Unit Test Failure.          Sources.
>   a.https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2752802
>   b.https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392181

Comment: You should upgrade to SonarQube 6.7 LTS

Comment: Thanks Jeroen Heier..I installed 6.7 version and tried using the above rest apis..But the apis didnt work..Thats why i am using 6.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

[SonarCloud](https://sonarcloud.io), an online version of SonarQube, is updated by SonarSource and will allways contain the latest features. Have a look at the SonarCloud API documentation:

- [api/issues/search](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/issues)
- [api/resources](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/resources)

api/resources is deprecated since 5.4 and dropped in 6.3. You should use [api/measures](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/measures)